Impossible to create release package for Xamarin android app
I’m trying to upload my app to google play console but i’m getting error that makes me mad. On console when i upload my aab file, i get “You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK or Android App Bundle in release mode”. but in VS for mac that I'm using, everything is in release mode. in compiler section of android project i try to set “none” to Debug Information but when i close the window and reopen it sets “full” automatically. What am I doing wrong? I also try to set android:debuggable="false" in androidmanifest but I’m still getting error
I tried android:debuggable="false", I tried to set "None" to Debug Info
